# Binding JSON array with HTML list using Knockout.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am new to knockout.js framework and I am stuck in a fairly simple problem of binding a JSON array with a html UL list. The html markup is given below :

```
<div id="genres">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: GenreCollection">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have used the following markup to capture the JSON data coming in as the data for template binding :

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

The JSON output is :

```
{
  "GenreCollection": [
    "Action & Adventure",
    "Action Comedies",
    "Action Sci-Fi & Fantasy",
    "Action Thrillers",
    "Anime Action",
    "Bollywood Action & Adventure",
    "British Action & Adventure",
    "Classic Action & Adventure",
    "Crime Action & Adventure",
    "Foreign Action & Adventure",
    "Independent Action & Adventure",
    "Military Action & Adventure",
    "Spy Action & Adventure",
    "TV Action & Adventure"
  ]
}
```

ViewModel :

```
    function viewModel(){
        var self = this;
        self.GenreCollection = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.addData = function (data) {
        for (var item in data) {            
            self.GenreCollection.push(data[item]);
        }
    }
}

GenreNamespace.bindData = function (data) {
    var obj = new viewModel();
    obj.addData(data);
    ko.applyBindings(obj);
}

GenreNamespace.getData = function (searchText) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Genre/SearchGenre',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(searchText),
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            GenreNamespace.bindData(data);
        },
        error: function (message) {
            alert(message);
        }
    });
}
```

Can one any one help me figuring out as what the problem is in the above html template. I am using VS 2012 and Knockout 2.1 framework.

Thanks

Comment: How do you call `GenreNamespace.bindData`?

Comment: Its a callback function after I have invoked the async ajax call. I have updated the question with the relevant code snippet.

Comment: From you question it's not clear what is your actual problem... What is the output what you get? Empty list, not the right elements in the list, etc?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The problem I am facing is that the data is that the list is not getting rendered. In other words, I would like to know if the way I am invoking ko.applyBinding() in the correct manner i.e. invoking it on every asycn callback. I can see the JSON data its just that its not getting rendered. The problem might be with the way I have setup my view model or the way I am calling ko.applyBinding().

Comment: Your KO code looks ok... Are you sure that you get the right data from the server? If you put an `alert(data);` in your success callback what do you see? What happens if you remove the `processData: false` from you ajax options? Why do you need `processData: false` in the first place?

Comment: Thankfully I am able to bind the data now. Although I have run into different problems this time. I guess I will have to go for a fresh start on KO this time. Anyways thanks for your help. If you want, you can reply to this post and I will mark it as answered. Thanks again.